# How to integrate a seperate component into the ExtJS application

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs6

I create a simple input element separately in Javascript.

My Code :

```
MyInput = function(args) {
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput"  list="myUL" onclick = "openingList()" onkeyup="openingList()" style="width:30%;" >';
    div.innerHTML = myTable;
}
```

Which I Kept in folder structure  **MyCombo/MyInput.js** and CSS is  **MyCombo/MyInput.js**. These two folder structure I pass in to app.json as well.

Now I want to use this on a form panel. I want to pass divID, width and someother arugments.

Suppose my form is like

```
Ext.define('FormTest.view.main.login', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
            xtype: 'login',
            title: 'Login Form',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            width: 350,
            url: 'save-form.php',
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Female',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Male',
                    allowBlank: false,
                },{
                    // Here I want to use My Input. 
                }
                ],
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function() {
                        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                    }
                }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
```

The specific position I want to use `MyInput`.

Currently I am accessing from some the `index.html` in third application like this.

```
var myInput = new myInput({
      "url": "data.json",
      "divID": "chart_line"
    });
```

can You please suggest me how to integrate this to my ExtJS application.

Note : I need to use this to my app, not Ext Component.

Comment: You can't. Containers understand `Ext.Component` and their subclasses. You can't just insert arbitrary stuff in there. You would need to at least wrap what your `MyInput` does in a component.

Comment: Can you please suggest any link or any example for "You would need to at least wrap what your MyInput does in a component".

Comment: Something like: `{ xtype: 'component', html: myInput } - also make sure MyInput returns the div you added the textfield to.

Comment: But here I need to pass the argument in div to create `myInput` function